# How can you tell if a stored procedure does not return results when using vb.net and linqtosql?

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I have a linqtosql dbml where I dropped a stored procedure into the designer interface.

Stored procedure name:
GetUser(@userid int)

```
Select * from users_tbl where userid=@userid
```

Now in the code I want to do something like this:

```
Dim db as new UserDataContext

Dim myuser as users_tbl = db.GetUser(1)
```

How can I tell if GetUser returned a user or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it returns a record, `users_tbl` will not be `null` and will not have a `.Count()` of 0.

Comment: Though GetUser returns a single record and users_tbl doesn't seem to have a .Count() method available.

I guess comparing null is the best here.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't be sure whether your particular procedure returned a collection or not.